# Camera orientation in android docs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera, orientation

I am not able to understand this piece of code from [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int))

What does `info.orientation` give and the **arithmetic calculations**?

```
int result;
if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
{
    result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
    result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
}
else      // back-facing
{
    result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
}
camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
```

This is the full code.

**setDisplayOrientation**

```
public final void setDisplayOrientation (int degrees)
```

Set the clockwise rotation of preview display in degrees. This affects the
preview frames and the picture displayed after snapshot. This method
is useful for portrait mode applications. Note that preview display of
front-facing cameras is flipped horizontally before the rotation, that
is, the image is reflected along the central vertical axis of the
camera sensor. So the users can see themselves as looking into a
mirror.

This does not affect the order of byte array passed in ***PreviewCallback#onPreviewFrame***, JPEG pictures, or recorded videos.
This method is not allowed to be called during preview. If you want to
make the camera image show in the same orientation as the display, you
can use the following code.

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```